# Search catalog with less than 3 characters

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

What is the solution to be able to search Magento 2 catalog with less than three characters.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;This is what i have done so far from looking at Magento 1 info regarding this issue.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Setting &quot;Max Query Lengt&quot; in backend to 2&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;Changed the mysql setting ft_min_word_len=2 and restarted the server.&#xD;&#xA;reindex and clear cache.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;I have also tried to move the following indexing tables to MyISAM and then run a REPAIR QUICK on them and update the indexes&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;    catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1&#xD;&#xA;    cms_block&#xD;&#xA;    cms_page&#xD;&#xA;    customer_grid_flat&#xD;&#xA;    sales_creditmemo_grid&#xD;&#xA;    sales_invoice_grid&#xD;&#xA;    sales_order_grid&#xD;&#xA;    sales_shipment_grid&#xD;&#xA;    catalogsearch_fulltext&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;The tricky thing with this is that bin/magento indexer:reindex changes them back to InnoBD. Don&#x27;t know if they are dropped and recreated or how that happens but that&#x27;s my result after a magento reindex.&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;The enginge change, repair, flushing and so on is done after magento reindex.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;If anyone have an idea where to go from here i would be quite happy?&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Thanks in advance&lt;br&gt;&#xD;&#xA;Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem. I resolved it adding 

    [mysqld]
    innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
    ft_min_word_len=1

(in your case equal to 2) to /etc/mysql/my.cnf inside the [mysqld] section, restart mysql daemon and then run:

    php bin/magento indexer:reindex

inside magento root directory.
With the innodb global variable which I wrote earlier the settings value also for the innodb engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check this and inform me whether it works or not

From the admin sidebar, navigate to Store>Configuration>Catalog and choose Catalog. After that, expand the Catalog Search section and do the following:
Set Minimal Query Length to the minimum number of characters that can be submitted in a query.
Set Maximum Query Length to the maximum number of characters that can be submitted in a query.
Set Search Engine as default.
In the Apply Layered Navigation if Search Results are Less Than field, enter the number of records that can be used with layered navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Minimum Length of your search query by changing the following configuration in Magento version 2.3 -> 2.4

`Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search > Minimal Query Length`

After setting this config value to 1, you minimum search character length will be set to 1. Lower query length can impact your search performance so just be mindful of that.